# Job getting aborted when triggered through ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks

Databricks job gets failed when it is called from adf with the error: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.`

error details:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 65536 bytes of memory, got 0
    at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.throwOom(MemoryConsumer.java:157)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.allocateArray(MemoryConsumer.java:97)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeInMemorySorter.<init>(UnsafeInMemorySorter.java:139)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.<init>(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:165)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.create(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.<init>(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.create(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:97)
```

I have tried giving retry 5 after every 500 sec, it used to solve the issue as it would run fine in one of the retries, but now even after 5 runs it gets errored out. But when tried directly from notebook it runs fine.

I think it is a memory issue, any solution to overcome this?

Comment: You might clear cache in when you start execution of your notebook!

Answer (score 0):

OOM (Out of Memory) errors are quite common when working with increasing loads, or increasing size of data. (or more shuffles?)

Sometimes it is common to get thrown an internal server error without OOM being specified, however it still being the cause.

In this case, error message states OOM, which means you should increase your memory or scale your cluster.

P.S: retry is not advised in OOM scenarios, as the error tends to become permanent after some time, such as when the cluster cannot take it anymore.